# Disable 'Enable SharePoint Designer' through feature?

Tags: feature

Is it possible to disable the SharePoint Designer Settings - 'Enable SharePoint Designer' within a feature activation event?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible with following property:

SPWebApplication.AllowDesigner

Comment: At the site collection level it is sitecol.AllowDesigner = false;